# SPSS 22 on Xubuntu 15.04; stats file not runable; errors

Tags: xubuntu

I'm trying to get SPSS 22 working under Xubuntu 15.04; it's the only piece of software I'm missing to make my migration to Linux complete.

Before you all start suggesting PSPP/R; my boss requires me to work in SPSS, because she knows and understand it, so unfortunately other software is not an option. Also, PSPP does not support many of the stats I have to do (like repeated measures ANOVA).

Alright, so I installed the software without problems up to the point where you licence it at the end, at which point I get an error about an internal problem with Ubuntu, which I sent off at the time but unfortunately I did not save (silly me!). However, it seems all the files are installed correctly. I am then supposed to start spss using the stats file in the /bin folder. If I try that, this happens;

```
narameh@Hydrogen:/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin$ ./stats
*** Error in `/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin/STATISTICS': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f37880050d0 ***
*** Error in `/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin/STATISTICS': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f3788005150 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I searched around a bit online and installed;

```
lib32z1
lib32ncurses5
libstdc++5
```

as this seemed to have solved similar problems for others.

I also tried `gksudo`, but this still throws the first error, not the second;

```
narameh@Hydrogen:/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin$ gksudo ./stats
GNOME_SUDO_PASS
*** Error in `/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin/STATISTICS': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f0a6400a130 ***
```

I then took a look at the contents of the stats file;

```
#!/bin/sh
SPSS_HOME=/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22
cd /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22
. /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin/statsenv.sh
exec /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/bin/STATISTICS "$@"
```

As `#!/bin/sh` is not quite `#!/bin/bash` I tried creating a file called spss.sh, made it executable and put in the same code with #!/bin/bash instead. No dice.

Anyone has any more input on how to make this baby work? Rebooting in windows takes ages every time I try it. I am a relatively new Linux user, so please be so kind as to keep that in mind if/when you answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 15.04 and SPSS 22, I followed the same steps you did, up to creating a new #!/bin/bash script. I got the same errors.

However, I was able to install and run SPSS 23 with no problems. I didn't use `gksudo`, but I still had these 3 packages installed: `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libstdc++5`

Answer (score 0):

The official IBM Fix Pack FP002 for SPSS22 on Linux x64 fixes this issue. It can be found [here](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=SPSS&product=ibm/Information%20Management/SPSS%20Statistics&release=22.0.0.0&platform=Linux%2064-bit,x86_64&function=all) (requires registration).

In my case, on Ubuntu 15.10, this makes stats executable without errors. Ubfortunately, SPSS still won't start...